# Integer is being returned as 0 when it shouldn't be. Retrieved from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I'm trying to get a value from my database but it keeps returning a value of 0 and i cannot figure out why. I've been retrieving data from the database for the whole of my project and it is just not working here. None of the values in the database are = to 0.

int rentalPrice is the one being returned as 0`

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (Request.QueryString["id"] == null) 
       {
           Response.Redirect("DisplayCars.aspx");
       }
       else
       {
           id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd.CommandText = "select * from cars where id ='" + id + "'";
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           lblCarID.Text = id.ToString();
           DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
           SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
           {
               rentalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["car_rental_price"]);
           }
           lblRentalPrice.Text = rentalPrice.ToString();

           con.Close();
       }
```

Comment: You're using `ExecuteNonQuery`. But you're trying to execute a query. See how that doesn't make any sense? Have you looked in the documentation at what [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) returns?

Comment: **warning:** fyi you are asking for sql injection!!!

Comment: side note: why this line `Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());` ? You are adding the `id` value as a string to the query but you read it as a string, convert it to an int, and then add it as a string and also as varchar. Really you should be using parameterized sql and the id in the database should be of type int.

Comment: You're creating a `DataTable`, but you never populate it.  You don't need the `ExecuteNonQuery` you need a `da2.Fill(dt2)`.  There are other problems, but that seems to be the main issue here.

Answer (score 2):

```
// This uses a Connection pool, so you don't need to reuse the same SqlConnection
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
{        
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select [car_rental_price] from cars where id = @Id";
        var idParam = new SqlParameter("@Id");
        idParam.Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(idParam);
        con.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExcecuteReader()) 
        {
            reader.Read();
            lblRentalPrice.Text = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
            lblCarID.Text = id.ToString();} 
        }
    }
 }
```

To execute a query and get results, you need to use `cmd.ExecuteReader`.

Also, rather than concatenating values into a string to build your SQL query, you need to use parameterized queries. This helps prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Also, SqlConnection should not be put in a field (class level variable). Instead, you should use local variables and wrap them in a `using` statement to ensure that they get disposed of properly.

Comment: I would agree, but I couldn't really do that since I didn't see its declaration. :)

Answer (score -2):

hey you did not fill the Data Table.. then how it has any Values???

first Fill the data Table and use it in Foreach loop

```
adapter.Fill(DataTable);
foreach(DataRow dr in DataTable)
{
  //get the id
}
```